# Why i can not launch my hipster java project?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, jhipster

I want to create an java app using jhipster yeoman generator. 
1. I followed instruction [here from the installation manual](http://jhipster.github.io/installation.html)
2. Then i went to the [following page](http://jhipster.github.io/creating_an_app.html) and create the app. Things work as expected.
When  i run the application with `mvn spring-boot:run` i get some errors. What is wrong with my configuration ? Is there something else to do ?
I don't know if i am right. I choose the mysql database. I think i have to create and configure the database. Why is it not mentionned in the official documentation ?
Here is the stacktrace  :

```
[INFO] Compiling 82 source files to C:\Programming\WORKSPACE_JHIPSTER\hubtalents\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ hubapp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ hubapp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ hubapp <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ hubapp ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
[INFO] com.daytech.hubtalents.Application - Starting Application on Kevin-PC with PID 5272 (C:\Programming\WORKSPACE_JHIPSTER\hubtalents\target\classes started by Kevin in C:\Programming\WORKSPACE_JHIPSTER\hubtalents)
[DEBUG] com.daytech.hubtalents.Application - Running with Spring Boot v1.2.0.RELEASE, Spring v4.1.3.RELEASE
[DEBUG] org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
[DEBUG] com.daytech.hubtalents.config.AsyncConfiguration - Creating Async Task Executor
[DEBUG] com.daytech.hubtalents.config.MetricsConfiguration - Registering JVM gauges
[INFO] com.daytech.hubtalents.config.MetricsConfiguration - Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
[DEBUG] com.daytech.hubtalents.config.DatabaseConfiguration - Configuring Datasource
[ERROR] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener - Error starting Tomcat context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
[WARN] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474) ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.daytech.hubtalents.Application.main(Application.java:56) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:97) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:74) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:374) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:150) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:148) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:121) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.daytech.hubtalents.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.daytech.hubtalents.repository.UserRepository com.daytech.hubtalents.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#76ce45bb' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#76ce45bb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/daytech/hubtalents/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: : Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/daytech/hubtalents/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/daytech/hubtalents/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:371) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:176) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:141) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:136) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:119) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:69) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:216) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:202) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener.java:64) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5095) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.daytech.hubtalents.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.daytech.hubtalents.repository.UserRepository com.daytech.hubtalents.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#76ce45bb' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#76ce45bb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/daytech/hubtalents/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: : Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/daytech/hubtalents/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/daytech/hubtalents/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:646) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.daytech.hubtalents.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.daytech.hubtalents.repository.UserRepository com.daytech.hubtalents.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#76ce45bb' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#76ce45bb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/daytech/hubtalents/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: : Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/daytech/hubtalents/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/daytech/hubtalents/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164) ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:603) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.daytech.hubtalents.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.daytech.hubtalents.repository.UserRepository com.daytech.hubtalents.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#76ce45bb' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#76ce45bb': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/daytech/hubtalents/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.sql.DataSource]: : Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/daytech/hubtalents/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/daytech/hubtalents/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
```

The complete log are available at [pastebin](http://pastebin.fr/37933)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using HikariCP and your datasource cannot establish a successful initial connection:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail-fast during pool initialization`

There are quite a few potential causes why that might happen - I would recommend bootstrapping only your persistence layer in a simple integration test and looking at the exact cause of the failure.

Answer (score 0):

Enable DEBUG logging for com.zaxxer.hikari it may give you additional information.  For Spring auto-wired dependencies you may need to use `jdbcUrl`/`driverClassName` rather than `dataSourceClassName`-based configuration.